# Any reason I can't use popover batter to make one huge popover without separating into little cups?

Tags: baking, batter

Something like http://www.food.com/recipe/perfect-popovers-189284 but all in one baking pan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely can do that. Brits call it [Yorkshire Pudding](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/tyler-florence/yorkshire-pudding-recipe.html), and the technique is actually fairly forgiving. You can make them muffin sized, or you can make one big popover. Just don't mess around, popovers get their "pop" from steam. A medium cast-iron skillet (9 inches or 23 cm, roughly) is perfect, you can do it in a square tin too.

My British buddy says: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25537746#25537746

Comment: So *this* is what Yorkshire Pudding is? Fantastic. That sounds so much more fancy than popover. I'm going to start using this.

Comment: @user40902 One of my best friends on this board is an actual Brit, he makes Yorkshire Pudding all the time. I'll probably see him in a few hours; I'll ask him for his favorite recipe and post it in my answer.

Comment: Popovers and yorkshire puddings are not the same @Jolenealaska , although they are similar. Popover batter has much more egg in it. Popovers come out more elastic and yorkshire puds have a more crispy texture. Still, I agree you could make a big popover in a tray or pan.

Comment: There's also the "Dutch Baby" style pancake, which can be made in either a muffin tin, casserole dish or a cast iron skillet : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_baby_pancake

Answer (score 0):

You can, but the bottom may not be as flaky. You'll get something more like an entamens turn over than a fresh pastry.